# CancellationToken in Dropbox C# SDK?

Tags: c#, dropbox-api

How can I cancel `Task<>` from `async` methods in Dropbox C# SDK? 
 I don't see how I can set `CancellationToken` for them. I thought there is something like it in API methods:

```
public Task<Metadata> GetMetadataAsync(
    string path,
    bool includeMediaInfo = false,
    bool includeDeleted = false,
    bool includeHasExplicitSharedMembers = false,
    CancellationToken ct = null /*This is would be optional cancellation token. But this parameter doesn't exist in API*/
);
```

But can't find it. It would be good approach for cancel asynchronous operation.

Comment: You don't know how to create the CancellationToken, is this your problem?

Comment: @RodrigoVedovato, My problem is how to set CancellationToken to Dropbox C# SDK. It's important for cancel API awaiting task.  Look [How do I cancel non-cancelable async operations?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations/)

Comment: @Hakam Fostok, Thank you for good redaction of my ask.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/CancellationToken/m-p/220956#M11721 ]

Answer (score 0):

[Greg's answer](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/CancellationToken/m-p/221276/highlight/true#M11738):

The Dropbox API v2 .NET SDK doesn't support cancelling/cancellation tokens, but I'll be sure to pass this along as a feature request.